# Can smart contracts be used to mint native assets?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, native-assets

Cardano doesn't need to use smart contracts to mint native assets. But is it possible to mint native assets using smart contracts? And if so, is there an example how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the subject of week 5 of the plutus pioneer program. You can find examples in the [Github repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/main/code/week05/src/Week05).

In the `Signed.hs` module, there's an example for how to mint tokens, and the `NFT.hs` for how to mint Non Fungible Tokens.

There's also a [full lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsaVjSsPPcg) on that subject by Lars.

Answer (score 1):

Agree to start with Lecture 5.  If you can't wait for the Plutus Application Backend to get deployed, there is also and exercise in Alonzo Purple for minting a NFT using the Command Line Interface CLI.  You can find it at the Alonzo github repository.

Comment: What's the link?